# SDL2 Transparent surface

Tags: c++, windows, sdl-2

I am trying to create a transparent surface, blit it bigger surface (size of my screen), then create a texture of it, copy to the renderer, and finaly render present.

I have seen many other forums saying I have to use SetBlendMode (for surface, texture, and renderer), ColorKey, SetSurfaceBlendMode. I tried them all but I can't seem to get it to work. I read that SDL_BlitScaled is not suitable for combining surfaces that have transparent pixels, but I am completely lost as to what I have to do instead.

What I noticed, when I use SDL_CreateRGBSurface (with an alpha value) to create a surface, the surface's PixelFormat is RGB888 instead of RGBA8888 (what I am expecting since I provide the alpha value). Using SDL_ConvertSurfaceFormat did not help.

**Can somebody tell me what I am missing?**

Complete code: *removed, my appologies*

*Please note that I have removed the attempts to get transparency working*

The renderer:

```
mRenderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(mWindow, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED);
```

My render loop:

```
void CApp::Render()
{
    SDL_RenderClear(mRenderer);

    mBackGround->Render(mRenderer);
    mForeGround->Render(mRenderer);

    SDL_RenderPresent(mRenderer);
}
```

The big surface I am blitting to:

```
mSurface = SDL_CreateRGBSurface(0, CApp::Window_W(), CApp::Window_H(), 32, 0, 0, 0, 0);
```

The code to get tiles from a spritesheet:

```
bool Map::GetTilesFromSpriteSheet(SDL_Surface *pSpriteSheet, int pTile_w, int pTile_h)
{
    if(pSpriteSheet->w % pTile_w == 0 && pSpriteSheet->h % pTile_h == 0) {
        SDL_Rect srcRect;
        srcRect.w = pTile_w;
        srcRect.h = pTile_h;
        for(int y = 0; y < pSpriteSheet->h / pTile_h; y++) {
            for(int x = 0; x < pSpriteSheet->w / pTile_w; x++) {
                srcRect.x = x*pTile_w;
                srcRect.y = y*pTile_h;
                SDL_Surface* tempSurface = SDL_CreateRGBSurface(0, pTile_w, pTile_h, 32, 0, 0, 0, 0);
                if(SDL_BlitSurface(pSpriteSheet, &srcRect, tempSurface, nullptr)==0) {
                    mTiles.push_back(tempSurface);
                } else {
                    Log("Error extracting tile (%d,%d)(w,h): %s", x, y, SDL_GetError());
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        Log("Number of tiles: %d", static_cast<int>(mTiles.size()));
    } else {
        Log("Background spritesheet is incompatible with tile dimensions (%d,%d)(w,h).", pTile_w, pTile_h);
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

This is where I combine the tiles to create the big surface:

```
bool Map::GenerateMap(std::vector<std::vector<int>> &pMap, std::vector<SDL_Surface*> &pTiles, SDL_Surface* pDestination)
{
    SDL_Rect rect;
    rect.w = mDstTile_W;
    rect.h = mDstTile_H;
    SDL_Surface* transparent = SDL_CreateRGBSurface(0, mDstTile_W, mDstTile_H, 32, 0, 0, 0, 0);

    for(int y = 0; y < static_cast<int>(pMap.size()); y++) {
        for(int x = 0; x < static_cast<int>(pMap.at(static_cast<unsigned long>(y)).size()); x++) {
            rect.x = x*mDstTile_W;
            rect.y = y*mDstTile_H;
            int index = static_cast<int>(pMap.at(static_cast<unsigned long>(y)).at(static_cast<unsigned long>(x)));
            if(index < 0) {
                if(SDL_BlitScaled(transparent, nullptr, pDestination, &rect) != 0) {
                    Log("Error blitting transparent surface to destination: %s", SDL_GetError());
                }
            } else if(SDL_BlitScaled(pTiles[static_cast<unsigned long>(index)],
                              nullptr, pDestination, &rect) != 0) {
                Log("Error blitting surface to destination: %s", SDL_GetError());
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    SDL_FreeSurface(transparent);
    return true;
}
```

And finaly, this is the code to render the big surface to the screen, first by creating a texture:

```
void ForeGround::Render(SDL_Renderer* pRenderer)
{
    if(mTexture) SDL_DestroyTexture(mTexture);
    mTexture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(pRenderer, mSurface);

    if(mTexture == nullptr) {
        Log("Unable to create foreground texture: %s", SDL_GetError());
    } else if (SDL_RenderCopy(pRenderer, mTexture, nullptr, nullptr)) {
        Log("Unable to render foreground: %s", SDL_GetError());
    }
}
```

Comment: None of your surfaces have alpha channel. `CreateRGBSurface(..., 32, 0, 0, 0, 0)` is meaningless as masks are not defined, but for convenience SDL treats it as RGB888 (reflected in documentation for said function). `CreateRGBSurface(..., 32, 0x000000ff, 0x0000ff00, 0x00ff0000, 0)` once again creates RGB888 because alpha channel mask is 0-wide. Use e.g. `32, 0xff, 0xff00, 0xff0000, 0xff000000` for all of your surfaces (arguably you don't need alpha for background but class inheritance is already a disaster). Recreating texture on each frame is slow, better use streaming texture and lock+memcpy.

Comment: @keltar Amazing how stupid my mistake was. I saw people using it but I didn't get why. I do now, thank you so much!

Just a follow up question, do you mean class inheritance is a disaster the way I did it or in general?

Also, I can answer my own question with your suggestion or you can post it as a solution?

Comment: Sure, post your answer if question is resolved, that's fine. I'm sorry for a 'disaster' bit, as it is very much opinion based. If you think it is useful for you - that's good. If it bites eventually - still good, now you know why.

Comment: Please indulge me, why do you think it is a disaster? The object oriented way has been self taught, and I am still learning!

I agree, the background does not need the transparency but I also think it cannot hurt too much. However, I also do not know if I will keep it to a 2 layer map (background + foreground). Perhaps I'll add an additional layer, not sure yet. I plan on crossing that bridge when I get to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @keltar mentioned, I was not creating surfaces with an alpha value.

I had to change the `SDL_CreateRGBSurface` call. The code snippet below creates an empty, transparent surface where I can blit to if needed (for example, tiles from a spritesheet).

```
SDL_Surface* tempSurface = SDL_CreateRGBSurface(..., 32, 0xff, 0xff00, 0xff0000, 0xff000000);
```

The code snippet below creates a black, non-transparent surface.

```
SDL_Surface* tempSurface = SDL_CreateRGBSurface(..., 32, 0xff, 0xff00, 0xff0000, 0x00000000);
```

This was enough for me, I did **not** have to use `SDL_SetRenderDrawBlendMode`, `SDL_SetSurfaceBlendMode`, `SDL_SetTextureBlendMode`, or `SDL_ConvertSurface`. A quick look at the SDL wiki showed:

> By default surfaces with an alpha mask are set up for blending as with
>
> SDL_SetSurfaceBlendMode(surface, SDL_BLENDMODE_BLEND)

Which explained why I did not have to call any of those functions. A big shout-out to keltar for his quick answer!

Comment: The documentation https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_CreateRGBSurface suggests that you should check the byte order (endianness) of the machine.